# Let $F|K$ be a field extension and $a \in F $ such that $[K(a):K]$ is odd integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F|K$ be a field extension and $a \in F$ such that $[K(a):K]$ is odd integer,

> > then prove that $K(a)=K(a^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a$ satisfies a quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $K(a)$ we have
$[K(a):K(a^2)]=1$ or $2$. In the former case there's nothing to prove.

In the latter case we get
$$
[K(a):K]=[K(a):K(a^2)][K(a^2):K]=2[K(a^2):K].
$$
But this is impossible because $[K(a):K]$ is odd.

Comment: How $a$ satisfies a quadratic poly?

Comment: @yiokk : Since $(a)^2=a^2$, the element $a$ always satisfies $X^2-a^2\in K(a^2)[X]$.